# SQL issues on load data?

Tags: sql

while i'm doing a lab on Jupyter notebook with SQL , I have this message

> "Error for batch element #1: The statement failed because the
>   authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege
>   to perform the operation. Authorization ID: "LXX49934". Operation:
>   "CREATE TABLE". Object: "AUDIT.SCHOOLS".. SQLCODE=-551,
>   SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.26.14 Number of occurrences: 1"

you can help me please

Comment: Seems like you don't have the proper authority to run a CREATE TABLE command within the database. How are your user privileges defined within the AUDIT database?

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sqlcode-551-or-sql0551n-when-user-privileges-are-defined-group